# EF6 - Code First - Are property mappings needed?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have been reading up on code first approach with entity framework.  Unfortunately I can't find much documentation than what relates to EF4 on this.  But the docs I have read (scott gu's blog on EF4) indicate that I don't need mappings.

So I generated a code files from an existing database using the EF6 Power Tools this generates all my model classes and a mappings folder.  Automatically I looked at the mappings files in there which are using the Fluent API (I think this is correct) and describe details about the tables.

Now reading this makes sense that it possibly wouldn't know the Primary Key, Required Properties, Relationships but the thing I don't get is the Property to Column Mappings from the blog post these were not needed so why do I need them?

I can understand needing them if a column name can't be represented in code but my naming conventions don't allow this.

My main reason for asking is a maintainability question I would rather only have code for a particular property in one place and these lines `this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");` seem redundant to me.

Any one with any helpful links on EF6 code first approach would be appreciated as well google is failing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly don't need property mappings if you're satisfied with the default column names and so on.  You may need them for things like setting the order of columns in a compound primary key, or specifying that a property contains a database-generated value (like an identity/autoincrement column), but even then you can leave the column names out of it and stick with the defaults.

Column mappings do have some uses, but I'm not sure any of them are relevant to your situation:

- You can map your entities to an existing database without having to mimic the column names, which may not follow standard .NET naming conventions.
- Similarly, you can follow different naming conventions in your code vs. in your database.  For example, where I work, database columns are usually expected to be camelCase, not PascalCase.
- They allow you to change the names of your properties at a later date without having to recreate/migrate your database.

If none of those apply to you, then yeah, I think you're probably fine without them.

Comment: I ended up customizing the conversion process to remove them and things seem ok need more testing yet though.

Answer (score 1):

EF use conventions to do a lot.  Once you know and feel comfortable with conventions you can declare classes and things just work.

[Code first conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962)